# How to give Magnifying glass effect in EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to give a magnifying glass effect to the EditText.As it gives on Searching view in iPhone.
    Is it possible to do in Android ? How can I do this?
Please Help Me

Answer (score 2):

Using an EditText you have this option:

Una opción usando el `EditText` es definiendo el icono, y usando la propiedad `android:hint` para el texto:

defining the icon with `android:drawableLeft` and the hint with `android:hint`

[image]

But the rigth way is using the [**SearchView**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView) widget:

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchProduct"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Should be do able. You can use getSelectionStart() to get where the cursor is , get the text & display a new textBox above the editText box with a larger text size .